# Count of a particular string in given line using regex java

Tags: java, regex

I have a line for ex
HelloxyzxyzxyzHello

I have a below regex to match this line

```
private static final Pattern matchPat = Pattern.compile("Hello(xyz)*Hello");
String line = "HelloxyzxyzxyzHello";
Matcher x8 = matchPat.matcher(line);
```

Now I would like to get the count of xyz
In my line it is 3

Is there a ready API available from regex other than finding a each matching pattern and use counter.

Comment: did you want to count the xyz which was present inside two hello's?

Comment: is it sure that xyz will occur between Hello only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex to get all the `xyz` count which was present inside two `Hello` substrings.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hello = "HelloxyzxyzxyzHello";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:Hello|(?<!^)\\G)(?:(?!Hello).)*?(xyz)(?=.*?Hello)");
        Matcher  matcher = pattern.matcher(hello);

        int count = 0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            if (matcher.group(1)) {
            count++;
             }
         }
        System.out.println(count);    // prints 3
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zC8mG5/3)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hello = "HelloxyzxyzxyzHello";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("xyz");
        Matcher  matcher = pattern.matcher(hello);

        int count = 0;
        while (matcher.find())
            count++;

        System.out.println(count);    // prints 3
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Capturing Groups**

```
String line = "This order was placed for QT3000! OK?";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(\\d+)(.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("group 1: " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("group 2: " + matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println("group 3: " + matcher.group(3));
}
```

Comment: I wanted a solution with out the counter. My input line can be a very big line and I might have a specific regex which has more than one group. I want to know no of occurrences of each group. In the example I just gave simple one.